# Underline showing in Material -UI InputBase component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a search bar comprised of an InputBase component.
Why is there an underline? InputBase is supposed to be plain(no decorations)
Here is the github link to the project.
https://github.com/brayomwas/codelab.
The search bar is under src/components

Answer (score 0):

use the `disableUnderline`  prop

```
<InputBase 
   className={classes.input}
   placeholder='Search'
   InputProps={{'aria-label': 'search', disableUnderline : true }}
/>
```

or use makeStyles

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  underline: {
    "&&&:before": {
      borderBottom: "none"
    },
    "&&:after": {
      borderBottom: "none"
    }
  }
});


<InputBase 
   className={classes.input}
   placeholder='Search'
   InputProps={{'aria-label': 'search',classes }}
/>
```